# ACT LED is not blinking but it is blinking for another RPi inserting same sd card

Tags: hardware, boot-issues

When i insert sd card to my RPi2 model B, ACT led doesnt blink but it blinks for another rpi using same SD card.SD card & ethernet is fine.

Is there any problem with my RPi?
If so, how can i determine it?

Comment: Most probably you're trying to use old version of raspbian on Rpi 2. Is green LED steady when trying to boot Rpi 2 ? If yes, grab the latest raspbian or run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` on Rpi 1 and update Raspbian.

Comment: its latest OS & green LED remains ON for smtime & than gets OFF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't necessarily notice the ACT light blinking; on a successful boot, once the kernel loads the ACT light only indicates SD card activity, whereas with a boot which fails before the kernel loads it will produce a regular pattern of blinks, possibly repeated in a loop, or (on the 2/+ models) if there is no SD card (or the reader does not like the card), a solid green ACT<sup>1</sup>.

Note on the A/B models, no SD card will not light ACT, which could be confused with a successful boot.

**However**, since there is generally more SD card action than just loading the kernel at boot, usually there will be irregular flickering for few seconds.  Not noticing any, i.e., just getting a steady PWR, does not necessarily mean the boot failed, but it could, as a result of a kernel/init hang or hardware damage -- you would have to plug in a screen to tell the difference between these three things (successful boot, broken hardware, kernel or init hang).

Put another way, no ACT light could indicate:

- A successful boot of the OS.
- A kernel hang or subsequent OS problem.
- On A/B models, no SD card/an improperly inserted card/a card the reader does not like.

---

<sup>1. This includes formatted cards that weren't intended for use in the pi.</sup>

Comment: Thank u.. I would connect it to monitor & than would try to figure out the problem

Comment: Based on your other comment the light is solid green (in the question it's ambiguous whether it is on or off, you just say "not blinking").  On a 2/+ model this indicates an SD card problem.

Comment: I have tried with the different SD card also, but getting same problem (ACT LED is solid green).

Comment: I just noticed this will happen with a card that is vfat formatted, but for a different purpose (I tried one from a camera).   If the card works in another pi, this is then a bit strange.  Did it *ever* work in that pi?  If not, are they identical?  I.e., not just the same model, but in [all characteristics](http://goughlui.com/2015/02/19/the-raspberry-pi-2-not-all-from-the-uk/).  I'm sure it is possible to have two Pi 2's with some variation in the SD card reader, and some of them do not like particular brands of card.

Comment: Yes once it worked in my Rpi2. I did configuration in putty (giving static ip address & netmask). While updating putty stopped & after that getting this problem. Yesterday i inserted my SD card to RPi model B , it was working fine.

Comment: I am using sandisk ultra 8 GB SD card